# best way to implement transactions in spring on tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, jboss, transactions

We have a new project am start. As a framework is Spring 3.1 and Spring Data JPA already decided. Dispute goes about the best options for the application server. Tomcat vs. JBoss. I am at the team Tomcat. My challenge to figure out the best way to manage transactions with Spring+Tomcat. He should at least   give  capabilities of a JBoss. I currently have in this area rather limited experience. I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

just decalre a transactionmanger (I use hibernate) :

```
<!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
```

then annotate the methods or classes as transactional. [Tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.7/reference/transaction.html).

I chose tomcat over jboss btw. Tomcat is something like ~15mb, the spring jars another 5mb. Compare this to the half gig behemoth that is jboss, and it just feels wrong to use it.